# Disabling Desktop Composition using Lua Scripting

Tags: lua, dwm

Im using Set-Up Factory from IndigoRose for building my installers. Set-up factory uses lua language in the scripting section of the installers.  Now, for my application once the installing is done, I would like to run a script which disables desktop decomposition if the operating system is windows 7.  Is there a way I can access dwmapi.lib  in lua for doing it.
Is there a system library function to access desktop window manager?

I have done some googling and found out the following code for vbscript..

```
Private Const DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION As Long = 0
Private Const DWM_EC_ENABLECOMPOSITION As Long = 1

Private Declare Function DwmEnableComposition Lib "dwmapi" (uCompositionAction As Long) As Long

Private Function SUCCEEDED(hr As Long) As Boolean
    SUCCEEDED = (hr >= 0)
End Function
Private Function FAILED(hr As Long) As Boolean
    FAILED = (hr < 0)
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
    If SUCCEEDED(DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION)) Then
        MsgBox "Vista Aero est Desactive"
    Else
        MsgBox "Vista Aero n'a pas pu etre Desactive"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer)
    MsgBox Cancel
    MsgBox UnloadMode
    If SUCCEEDED(DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_ENABLECOMPOSITION)) Then
        MsgBox "Vista Aero est Active"
    Else
        MsgBox "Vista Aero n'a pas pu etre active"
    End If

End Sub
```

How can I do this in LUA??

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have header files and you directly want to access functions from a DLL (dwmapi.dll) from Lua, you would have to try on of the "foreign function interface" libraries out there. Look at the section ["C Foreign Function Interfaces" on the Lua Wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BindingCodeToLua) for links to Alien (wraps libffi), LuaJIT FFI (if you want to use LuaJIT), and C/Invoke Lua.