# Calling Library in Lua

Tags: lua

I have created a Wireshark dissector in Lua for an application over TCP. I am attempting to use zlib compression and base64 decryption.  How do I actually create or call an existing c library in Lua?

The documentation I have seen just says that you can get the libraries and use either the `require()` call or the `luaopen_` call, but not how to actually make the program find and recognize the actual library.  All of this is being done in Windows.

Comment: For base64 decryption in Lua, see [lbase64](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lbase64).

Answer (score 3):

You *can't* load any existing C library, which was not created for Lua, with plain Lua. It's not trivial at least.

`*.so/*.dll` must follow some specific standard, which is bluntly mentioned in [programming in Lua#26.2](http://www.lua.org/pil/26.2.html) and [lua-users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LoadLibrary), [code sample](http://lua-users.org/wiki/EasyManualLibraryLoad). Also similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4162161/1150918).

There are two ways You could solve Your problem:

1. Writing Your own Lua `zlib` library wrapper, following those standards.
2. Taking some already finished solution:

   - [zlib@luapower](http://luapower.com/zlib.html)
   - [lua-zlib](https://github.com/brimworks/lua-zlib)
3. ffi

Bigger list [@lua-users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CompressionAndArchiving)

The same applies to `base64` encoding/decoding. Only difference, there are already plain-Lua libraries for that. Code samples and couple of links [@lua-users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BaseSixtyFour).

NOTE: Lua module package managers like [LuaRocks](http://luarocks.org) or
[LuaDist](http://luadist.org) **MIGHT** save You plenty of time.

Also, simply loading a Lua module usually consists of one line:

```
local zlib = require("zlib")
```

The module would be searched in places defined in Your Lua interpreter's [luaconf.h](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/luaconf.h.html) file.

For 5.1 it's:

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
/*
** In Windows, any exclamation mark ('!') in the path is replaced by the
** path of the directory of the executable file of the current process.
*/
#define LUA_LDIR        "!\\lua\\"
#define LUA_CDIR        "!\\"
#define LUA_PATH_DEFAULT  \
            ".\\?.lua;"  LUA_LDIR"?.lua;"  LUA_LDIR"?\\init.lua;" \
                         LUA_CDIR"?.lua;"  LUA_CDIR"?\\init.lua"
#define LUA_CPATH_DEFAULT \
    ".\\?.dll;"  LUA_CDIR"?.dll;" LUA_CDIR"loadall.dll"

#else
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I actually create or call an existing c library in Lua?

An arbitrary library, not written for use by Lua? You generally can't.

A Lua consumable "module" must be linked against the Lua API -- the same version as the host interpreter, such as Lua5.1.dll in the root of the Wireshark directory -- and expose a C-callable function matching the [lua_CFunction](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_CFunction) signature. Lua can load the library and call that function, and it's up to that function to actually expose functionality to Lua using the Lua API.

Your zlib and/or base64 libraries know nothing about Lua. If you had a Lua interpreter with a built-in FFI, or you found a FFI Lua module you could load, you could probably get this to work, but it's really more trouble than it's worth. Writing a Lua module is actually super easy, and you can tailor the interface to be more idiomatic for Lua.

I don't have zlib or a base64 C library handy, so for example's sake lets say we wanted to let our Lua script use the `MessageBox` function from the `user32.dll` library in Windows.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "lauxlib.h"

static int luaMessageBox (lua_State* L) {
    const char* message = luaL_checkstring(L,1);
    MessageBox(NULL, message, "", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

int __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl luaopen_messagebox (lua_State* L) {
    lua_register(L, "msgbox", luaMessageBox);
    return 0;
}
```

To build this, we need to link against `user32.dll` (contains `MessageBox`) and `lua5.1.dll` (contains the Lua API). You can get `Lua5.1.lib` from the Wireshark source. Here's using Microsoft's compiler to produce `messagebox.dll`:

```
cl /LD /Ilua-5.1.4/src messagebox.c user32.lib lua5.1.lib
```

Now your Lua scripts can write:

```
require "messagebox"

msgbox("Hello, World!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to use a library library like [alien](http://alien.luaforge.net/). See my answer [Disabling Desktop Composition using Lua Scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032642/disabling-desktop-composition-using-lua-scripting/22033294#22033294) for other FFI libraries.