# Display simple message box in Lua

Tags: io, lua

It sounds like a "let me google it for you" type of a question, but after some substantial amount of research, I couldn't find the answer.

Is there a built-in message box method in Lua? If not, what is the "standard" way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not built-in message box in Lua. You have to use a lua module like: [IupLua](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/)

Comment: Thank you, Alex.
I also found this method of using Windows standard message box: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22462842/4971456

Comment: Could you give an example instead of just linking to a library? Not to "player hate" an accepted answer, but it's well-established on SO that one-line answers linking to external resources should be made comments rather than answers.

Answer (score 4):

A message box is a GUI element and, as with many languages, not part of the standard. Either you use an external library ([list](http://lua-users.org/wiki/GraphicalUserInterfaceToolkits)), system libraries/native functions ([LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/) [FFI](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html)) or extend your interpreter with a [Lua C function](http://www.lua.org/pil/26.html).

I'd prefer LuaJIT. An example for windows:

```
local ffi = require("ffi")  -- Load FFI module (instance)

local user32 = ffi.load("user32")   -- Load User32 DLL handle

ffi.cdef([[
enum{
    MB_OK = 0x00000000L,
    MB_ICONINFORMATION = 0x00000040L
};

typedef void* HANDLE;
typedef HANDLE HWND;
typedef const char* LPCSTR;
typedef unsigned UINT;

int MessageBoxA(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);
]]) -- Define C -> Lua interpretation

user32.MessageBoxA(nil, "Hello world!", "My message", ffi.C.MB_OK + ffi.C.MB_ICONINFORMATION)   -- Call C function 'MessageBoxA' from User32
```